# Grouping of smaller cities (nearest) into larger cities

Tags: geocoding, geolocation, reverse-geocoding, geospatial-pdf

I have been looking for some suggestions on grouping of small cities (near by cities, places) into nearest largest cities (metro cities). For example, below are few cities from India.

```
Aluva, Kerala, India        |
Kanayannur, Kerala, India   |---> all these can be grouped to Kochi, Kerala, India
Kochi, Kerala, India        |
```

What I mean by larger cities, is like Metro city nearest to the sub cities. In my above India example, Kochi is the metro city, but Aluva, Kanayannur are some places nearer to Kochi.

In USA

```
Livermore, California, United States        |
Dublin, California, United States           |
Pleasanton, California, United States       |----> <<Nearest largest (Metro) city>>
San Ramon, California, United States        |
```

What I have is City, State, Country. I am looking for suggestions on how to approach this. Is there any list of these I can start from? In the India locations, I can make District as center point, and USA may I can make the county as central point. But it will be different when comes into European countries or in Canada etc.

Can someone suggest a way to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you consider to be *"a larger city"*? Which geocoder are you using?

Comment: what I mean by larger cities, is like Metro city nearest to the sub cities. In my above India example, Kochi is the metro city, but  Aluva, Kanayannur are some places nearer to Kochi. ( I have edited the question also)

Comment: @Community - I 've made edits in the question.